# Crear cliente Asíncrono para consumir WCF creado con SVCutil.exe

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, asynctask

Tengo mi WCF el cual solo devuelve un booleano, tiene el contrato creado y dentro de las pruebas del WCF todo funciona correctamente. El problema surge cuando creo el cliente y este no ejecuta los métodos de manera asíncrona.

Necesito conocer si existe una manera de que los métodos se ejecuten de manera Asíncrona.

Existe alguna manera de generar un método asíncrono con el SVCUtil y que funcione?

Esta es mi interfaz

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContractAttribute]
    bool booleanMethod();
}
```

Clase TestWCF.svc

```
public class TestWCF: IService1
{
    public bool BooleanMethod()
    {
        return BooleanMethod();
    }
}
```

Luego de esto genere mi clase con la sentencia svcUtil en el Developer Command Prompt.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El archivo creado lo coloque en mi Proyecto Xamarin y este funciona correctamente cuando uso mi metodo normal, pero al momento de usar el mismo metodo de manera asincrona me da un error.

```
bool Result = Test.BooleanMethod (); // Execute correct

bool ResultAsync = Test.BooleanMethodAsync (); // It does not execute correctly
```

Alguien me podría ayudar con las llamadas asincrónicas del cliente?

Comment: No deberia de ser `bool ResultAsync = await Test.BooleanMethodAsync();`? BooleanMethodAsync deberia de retornar un task. No?

Comment: Einer si tienes razón, ya lo hice de esa manera también pero de igual manera no funciona.

Comment: Puedes mostrar el error que te lanza?